# File created in Open XML SDK 2.5 crashes excel when selecting print

Tags: excel, openxml-sdk

I created an excel document in c# using the open xml 2.5 sdk.  The file opens in excel and works fine till I select print.  At this point, excel crashes with the error "Excel has stopped working".  I am using Excel 2016.  If I save the file first, before selecting print, the problem is fixed.

I was able to find the solution, but couldn't find this question on stackoverflow, so I'm posting and answering my own question.  If anyone has any comments for improvement or a better solution, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/54877ee3-25ee-47f8-9731-b1795bd4333a/openxml-excel-file-works-in-excel-2007-openoffice-etc-but-not-in-excel-2010) pointed me in the correct direction.  The issue was that I had not added bookviews to my file.  The solution in code is:

```
WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

BookViews bookViews = new BookViews();
WorkbookView workbookView = new WorkbookView();
bookViews.Append(workbookView);
workbookPart.Workbook.Append(bookViews);
```

In the original link, one of the comments mentions adding BookViews prior to Sheets.  I found this to be true.